# Reflection of asymptote in line of symmetry is also an asymptote

Tags: calculus

**Claim.** Let $f$ be a real-valued function of a real variable. Let $a$ be a line (that can be horizontal, vertical, or oblique). Suppose $f$ has line of symmetry $l$ and asymptote $a$. If $r$ is the reflection of $a$ in $l$, then $r$ is also an asymptote of $f$.

Is the above claim true? And if so, how might we prove it?

---

Definitions:

- The reflection of a point $(p,q)$ in a point $(r,s)$ is the point $(2r-p,2s-q)$.
- $f$ has line of symmetry $l$ if the reflection of a point in the graph of $f$ in the nearest point on $l$ is also in the graph of $f$.
- The non-vertical line $y=ax+b$ is an asymptote of $f$ if $\lim_{x\to\pm \infty} f(x)=ax+b$.
- The vertical line $x=c$ is an asymptote of $f$ if $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=\pm\infty$.

---

I think the above claim is false.

Counterexample:

[image]

Define $f:\mathbb{Z}^{-}\cup\mathbb{Z}^{+}\cup\left[-1,0\right)\cup\left[1,\infty\right)\setminus\left\{ -1/n:n\in\mathbb{Z},n\ge2\right\}$  by $$f\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
-x, & \text{if }x\in\mathbb{Z},\\
-1/x, & \text{if }x\notin\mathbb{Z}.
\end{cases}$$

Then $f$ has line of symmetry $y=x$ and asymptote $x=0$. The reflection of $x=0$ in $y=x$ is $y=0$, but $y=0$ is not an asymptote of $f$.

So perhaps the claim would be true if we also assumed $f$ is continuous?

Comment: I'd suggest working on a base case (even functions, e.g.), and then obtain the general result using a roto-translation.

Comment: If you write the definitions of asymptote and symmetry, the result should come quite easily, I believe. By the way, is $l$ a vertical line, or can it be oblique? Is $a$ an horizontal asymptote or can it be oblique too?

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni: $a$ can be horizontal, vertical, or oblique (I've now edited my Q to make this clearer). I've also added the definitions but I don't see how the result comes easily (please help if you can, thanks!)

Comment: @user182601 I just posted an answer. Note that in the OP you should replace $\lim_{x\to\pm \infty} f(x)=ax+b$ by $\lim_{x\to\pm \infty} (f(x)-ax-b)=0$. Variable $x$ has no meaning outside of $\lim_{x\to\pm \infty} (\dots)$.

Comment: @user182601 Adding that $f$ is continuous seems much too strong. You could add that either $f$ is defined on some interval where the asymptote takes place (meaning: $[r, +\infty)$, or $(-\infty, r]$, of $[a-\delta, a)$ or $(a, a+\delta]$ for an asymptote on $a$), or that if this is not true, $f$ can be prolongated by a function where this is true (and which is still symmetric, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Note: in a typical maths paper, this would be stated as obvious without a demonstration. Or, one would say that functions are specific cases of curves, function asymptotes are specific cases of curve asymptotes, and when a curve has an asymptote and is symmetrical, it also has the symmetrical asymptote.
So the following demonstration feels more of a "Yes, it can be done!" type than really useful or elegant. :-)
The fact it relies only upon analysis means different cases (vertical asymptote, oblique asymptote) have to be distinguished.

**1** - We'll first express the **symmetrical** of a point $(p,q)$ by a line $L: y=cx+d$.
As noted in the OP, if $(r,s)$ is the point in $L$ closest to $(p,q)$, the symmetrical is $(2r-p, 2s-q)$.

$(r-p, s-q)$ is orthogonal to $(1,c)$: $r-p+c(s-q)=0$
$(r,s) \in L: s = cr+d$
$r-p+c(cr+d-q)=0$
$\begin{cases}
r = \frac {p+cq-cd}{c^2+1}\\
s = \frac {cp+c^2q-c^2d+c^2d+d}{c^2+1} = \frac {cp+c^2q+d}{c^2+1} \\
\end{cases}$
Point symmetrical to $(p,q)$ is:
$\begin{cases}
2r-p = \frac {2p+2cq-2cd}{c^2+1} - \frac {c^2p+p}{c^2+1} = \frac {(1-c^2)p+2cq-2cd}{c^2+1}\\
2s-q = \frac {2cp+2c^2q+2d}{c^2+1} - \frac {c^2q+q}{c^2+1}= \frac {2cp+(c^2-1)q+2d}{c^2+1} \\
\end{cases}$

**2** - We first deal with the case of an **asymptote in $+\infty$** (the case in $-\infty$ being symmetrical).
$f$ has asymptote $A$ of equation $y=ax+b$: $\lim_{x \to +\infty} (f(x) - ax - b) = 0$
For any $(x, f(x))$, the symmetrical is $(x', f(x'))=(\frac {(1-c^2)x+2cf(x)-2cd}{c^2+1}, \frac {2cx+(c^2-1)f(x)+2d}{c^2+1})$.
Now we look for $a', b'$ such that $f(x') - a'x' - b' \to 0$ when $x \to +\infty$.
The line $y=a'x+b'$ should be the symmetrical to $y=ax+b$ by $L$.
Point $(0,0)$ has symmetrical $(\frac {-2cd}{c^2+1}, \frac {2d}{c²+1})$.
Point $(1,a)$ has symmetrical $(\frac {1-c^2+2ca-2cd}{c^2+1}, \frac {2c+(c^2-1)a+2d}{c^2+1})$.
So vector $(1,a)$ has symmetrical $(\frac {1-c^2+2ca}{c^2+1}, \frac {2c+(c^2-1)a}{c^2+1})$.
(As a side note, this actually shows that $f$ being a function imposes some conditions on $(a,b,c,d)$: the symmetrical of $x \to +\infty$ must be $x' \to -\infty$ or $x' \to$ some constant, but not $x' \to +\infty$.
This means $\frac {1-c^2+2ca}{c^2+1} \le 0$, equivalent to $1-c^2+2ca \le 0$, two cases:
$c > 0$ and $a \le \frac {c^2-1} {2c}$, or
$c < 0$ and $a \ge \frac {c^2-1} {2c}$)

Going back to finding $a', b'$, we will split upon the cases $1-c^2+2ca \ne 0$ or $=0$.

**case $1-c^2+2ca \ne 0$**, we should have $a' = \frac {2c+(c^2-1)a}{1-c^2+2ca}$.
So let's try $f(x')-a'x'$ with this $a'$:
$f(x')-a'x' = \frac {2cx+(c^2-1)f(x)+2d}{c^2+1} - \frac {2c+(c^2-1)a}{1-c^2+2ca} \frac {(1-c^2)x+2cf(x)-2cd}{c^2+1}$
which simplifies to $\frac {a(c^2+1)x - (c^2+1)f(x) + 2d(ca+1)}{1-c^2+2ca}$.
When $x \to +\infty$, this $\to \frac {-b(c^2+1) + 2d(ca+1)}{1-c^2+2ca}$, this is the $b'$ we were looking after.

**case $1-c^2+2ca = 0$**, we express $f(x) = ax+b+\epsilon$, with $\epsilon \to 0$ when $x \to + \infty$:
$x'=\frac {(1-c^2)x+2cf(x)-2cd}{c^2+1} = \frac {(1-c^2+2ca)x+2cb+2c\epsilon-2cd}{c^2+1}$
$= \frac {2c(b+\epsilon)-2cd}{c^2+1} \to \frac {2c(b-d)}{c^2+1}$.
So when $x' \to \frac {2c(b-d)}{c^2+1}$, $x \to +\infty$, $f(x) \to + \infty$.
$f(x') = \frac {2cx+(c^2-1)f(x)+2d}{c^2+1} \to \pm \infty$,
because $f(x) \sim ax$, so $2cx+(c^2-1)f(x) \sim (2c+(c^2-1)a)x$,
and we cannot have $2c+(c^2-1)a = 0$:
with $1-c^2+2ca=0$ it gives $(c^2-1)^2 = -4c^2$, which is impossible.
So there is a vertical asymptote on $x'= \frac {2c(b-d)}{c^2+1}$.

**3** - Now we deal with the case of a **vertical asymptote on $x=b$**.
When $x \to b$, the symmetrical $(x', f(x'))=(\frac {(1-c^2)x+2cf(x)-2cd}{c^2+1}, \frac {2cx+(c^2-1)f(x)+2d}{c^2+1})$ has the following behaviors:

- If $c=0$, the symmetrical is a vertical, opposite asymptote $(x', f(x')) = (x, -f(x)+2d)$.
- If $c \ne 0$, $x' \to \pm \infty$ and $f(x') \to \pm \infty$, the signs $\pm$ depending upon the signs of $c$ for $x'$ and $c^2-1$ for $f(x')$.
  Then $2cf(x')+(1-c^2)x' = \frac {((1-c^2)^2+4c^2)x+4cd-2cd+2c^3d} {c^2+1}$
  $= (c^2+1)x+2cd \to (c^2+1)b+2cd$.
  Which means there is an asymptote with equation $2cy' + (1-c^2)x' = (c^2+1)b+2cd$.

Comment: I think the claim is actually false. I added a counterexample to my Q above.

Comment: @user182601 My démonstration implicitely assumes that $f$ is defined everywhere, at least in a neighboroud of the asymptote. Which is not the case of your counterexample ($f$ is not defined on $-1/n, n \in \mathbb N$). Very nice trick, I had not envisaged that case.